# Changing font size on window resize

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, each

Hi guys I am working on little script which should take font size of any container which have ".text" class and resize it accordingly to main container size changes (on resize). This is what I managed to come up with. But sadly this takes allready modified text and modifies it infinity times on resize.

**So in general I need that this script would take all different fonts sizes and on window resize modify them only from original sizes which I defined in css.**

I would be really grateful for any advices!!

```
$(".text").each(function() {
    // getting how many times original size of container changed 
    var starter_height = $('#wrapper').height();
    var height_change = starter_height/602;

    totalHeight =  parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
    $(this).css({"font-size": totalHeight * height_change + "px"});
    console.log(totalHeight);
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you want your font-size to adjust according to screen sizes, use font-size in %. For eg: font-size: 100% is 14px on a normal laptop screen. You could do 110%, 90% or whatever you want. Also you might want to look up CSS Media Queries

Comment: Why not use `em` or something similar and change the `body` font size with media queries?

Comment: Or use `rem` (since that's `em` values but then *always* based on the document root's font) and use @Roope's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Thx guys.
I have managed to combine my idea and yours by using em with font size. Now I wont need to write many different media queries at least for font. I am also thinking to add extra "if" to update font not all the time on resize but by some margin.

Answer (score 0):

If your `font-size` should be proportional to the screen size, then you can use [`vw` and `vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

```css
.text-1 {
  font-size: 6vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-1">First Text</div>
```